# Repeat sections of dataframe based on a column value

Tags: python, pandas

I'm collecting data over the course of many days and rather than filling it in for every day, I can elect to say that the data from one day should really be a repeat of another day. I'd like to repeat some of the rows from my existing data frame into the days specified as repeats. I have a column that indicates which day the current day is to repeat from but I am getting stuck with errors.

I have found ways to repeat rows n times based a column value but I am trying to use a column as an index to repeat data from previous rows.

I'd like to copy parts of my "Data" column for Day 1 into the "Data" column for Day 3 , using my "Repeat" Column as the index. I would like to do this for many more different days.

```
data = [['1', 5,np.NaN], ['1',5,np.NaN],['1',5,np.NaN], ['2', 6,np.NaN],['2', 6,np.NaN],['2', 6,np.NaN], ['3',np.NaN,1], ['3',np.NaN,np.NaN],['3', np.NaN,np.NaN]] 

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Day', 'Data','repeat_tag'])
```

Comment: so for Day3, the Data column should have just the one entry where `repeat_tag` has an entry?

Comment: All the days have three different entries for the Data column. So the data column for Day 3 should have the same 3 entries as Day 1

Answer (score 0):

#### Setup

```
# Start with Valdi_Bo's expanded example data
data = [['1', 51, np.nan], ['1', 52, np.nan],     ['1', 53, np.nan],
        ['2', 61, np.nan], ['2', 62, np.nan],     ['2', 63, np.nan],
        ['3', np.nan, 1],  ['3', np.nan, np.nan], ['3', np.nan, np.nan],
        ['4', np.nan, 2],  ['4', np.nan, np.nan], ['4', np.nan, np.nan]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Day', 'Data', 'repeat_tag'])

# Convert Day to integer data type
df['Day'] = df['Day'].astype(int)

# Spread repeat_tag values into all rows of tagged day
df['repeat_tag'] = df.groupby('Day')['repeat_tag'].ffill()
```

#### Solution

```
# Within each day, assign a number to each row
df['obs'] = df.groupby('Day').cumcount()

# Self-join
filler = (pd.merge(df, df, 
                   left_on=['repeat_tag', 'obs'], 
                   right_on=['Day', 'obs'])
            .set_index(['Day_x', 'obs'])['Data_y'])

# Fill missing data
df = df.set_index(['Day', 'obs'])
df.loc[df['Data'].isnull(), 'Data'] = filler
df = df.reset_index()
```

#### Result

```
df
    Day  obs  Data  repeat_tag
0     1    0  51.0         NaN
1     1    1  52.0         NaN
2     1    2  53.0         NaN
3     2    0  61.0         NaN
4     2    1  62.0         NaN
5     2    2  63.0         NaN
6     3    0  51.0         1.0
7     3    1  52.0         1.0
8     3    2  53.0         1.0
9     4    0  61.0         2.0
10    4    1  62.0         2.0
11    4    2  63.0         2.0
```

Comment: @user11548079 great to hear!

Comment: It worked when I tried to run it on this example! Thank you!! When I move to my slightly more complicated example, I get the error:InvalidIndexError: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @user11548079, is each day guaranteed to have the same number of observations (rows)?

Comment: Ah ok, I think that might have been one of the issues, which I corrected but now I realize actually, that when all of my data is not identical within the data column for each day that an error will appear too. Is there a way around this?

Comment: @user11548079, sorry, I had wrongly assumed that each day would have only one unique data value. I've edited my answer using example data provided by Valdi_Bo (thank you!)

Comment: Thanks very much-- sorry about that, I wasn't careful enough to know to specify that in the original question. Good team effort :)

Answer (score 0):

I slightly extended your test data:

```
data = [['1', 51, np.nan], ['1', 52, np.nan],     ['1', 53, np.nan],
        ['2', 61, np.nan], ['2', 62, np.nan],     ['2', 63, np.nan],
        ['3', np.nan, 1],  ['3', np.nan, np.nan], ['3', np.nan, np.nan],
        ['4', np.nan, 2],  ['4', np.nan, np.nan], ['4', np.nan, np.nan]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['Day', 'Data', 'repeat_tag'])
```

Details:

- There are **4** days with observations.
- Each observation has **different** value (*Data*).
- To avoid "single day copy", values for day *'3'* are to be copied from
  day *'1'* and for day *'4'* from day *'2'*.

I assume that non-null value of *repeat_tag* can be placed in **only one**
observation for the "target" day.

I also added *obsNo* column to identify observations within particular day:

```
df['obsNo'] = df.groupby('Day').cumcount().add(1);
```

(it will be necessary later).

The first step of actual processing is to generate *replDays* table, where *Day*
column is the **target** day and *repeat_tag* is the **source** day:

```
replDays = df.query('repeat_tag.notnull()')[['Day', 'repeat_tag']]
replDays.repeat_tag = replDays.repeat_tag.astype(int).apply(str)
```

A bit of type manipulation was with *repeat_tag* column.
As this column contains *NaN* values and non-null values are *int*, this column is
coerced to *float64*. Hence, to get **string** type (comparable with *Day*) it
must be converted:

- First to *int*, to drop the decimal part.
- Then to *str*.

The result is:

```
  Day repeat_tag
6   3          1
9   4          2
```

(fill data for day 3 with data from day 1 and data for day 4 with data from day 2).

The next step is to generate *replData* table:

```
replData = pd.merge(replDays, df, left_on='repeat_tag', right_on='Day',
    suffixes=('_src', ''))[['Day_src', 'Day', 'Data', 'obsNo']]\
    .set_index(['Day_src', 'obsNo']).drop(columns='Day')
```

The result is:

```
               Data
Day_src obsNo      
3       1      51.0
        2      52.0
        3      53.0
4       1      61.0
        2      62.0
        3      63.0
```

As you can see:

- There is only one column of replacement data - *Data* (from day 1 and 2).
- MutliIndex contains both the day and observation number (both will be
  needed for proper *update*).

And the final part includes the following steps:

- Copy *df* to *res* (result), setting index to *Day* and *obsNo*
  (required for *update*).
- Update this table with data from *replData*.
- Move *Day* and *obsNo* from index back to "regular" columns.

The code is:

```
res = df.copy().set_index(['Day', 'obsNo'])
res.update(replData)
res.reset_index(inplace=True)
```

If you want, you can alse drop *obsNo* column.

And a remark concerning the solution by *Peter*:
If source data contains for any day **different** values, his code fails
with *InvalidIndexError*, probably due to lack of identification of
individual observations within particular day.
This confirms that my idea to add *obsNo* column is valid.

Comment: Thanks so much for your detailed response—the way you extended my data set example is precisely how my data set will look.
I get a couple of errors, perhaps as I am still quite new to using python (in a Jupyter notebook). 


When I run the line 
replDays = df.query('repeat_tag.notnull()')[['Day', 'repeat_tag']]
replDays.repeat_tag = replDays.repeat_tag.astype(int).apply(str)-- the following error shows: 

TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed. 
This also occurs when I run all the code at once. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I use Python version *3.7* and Pandas version *0.24.2*. Maybe you have some older version? Another hint: Assume the same type for both *Day* and *repeat_tag*, so the above "quirks" with conversion will not be needed.